# Create Table in spring r2dbc

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, r2dbc, spring-data-r2dbc

I have a spring r2dbc connection for a postgresql database and would like to Create a Table,

effectively the equivalent of SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS name (id, bigint);
```

how can I do it as DatabaseClient seems to only support select/insert?

Comment: `databaseClient().execute().sql()`?

Comment: Note: Newer versions will accept SQL directly via `databaseClient.execute(…)`, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/89.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Thomas Andolf said in the comment

`.execute().sql()` is indeed the correct approach

in my case i needed to block indefinitely for the result before continuing so i needed to append  `.fetch().all().collectList().block();`

Comment: You can also call `execute(…).then()` instead of fetching all rows.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use DatabaseClient to create your tables.
So when I faced the same problem as you I did something like the following code :

```
 fun postgresProcess(config: PostgresConfig): PostgresProcess {
        val runtime = PostgresStarter.getDefaultInstance()
        val exec = runtime.prepare(config)
        val postgres = exec.start()
        // connecting to a running Postgres and feeding up the database
        val conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://$host:$port/$database", username, password)
        conn.createStatement().execute("CREATE TABLE customer ( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, firstname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, lastname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);")
        return postgres
    }
```

At start, you could do something like this and after you can use database client.

I remember trying flyway without success. I would have liked to use the DatabaseClient. More code on my repo [github](https://github.com/mikrethor/customer-r2dbc/)